# How to set Formik InitialValues if field name is coming in props?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have to set Formik to something like

```
initialValues={{ location: initialValue }}>
```

The name of the field is 'key.location' passed down to as props 'location'.
How to set field name as 'key.location' instead of 'location' ?

Comment: make special value append to string `""+key.location` with initialValues={{ location: {key:{location:"special Value"}} }}>

Comment: I am still a bit confused about your question. Do you always know exactly that 1. You will be receiving a props called "location", 2. The formik field you want is "key.location". If yes to these two, I believe you can do `const {location} = props; ...; initialValues = {{"key.location": location}}`

Comment: Thank you for the responses. The Answer from @codedump resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can just do

```js
initialValues={{ "key.location": initialValue }}
```

Yo probably tried to do

```js
initialValues={{ key.location: initialValue }}
```

which will fail. Just making the key a string will solve your problem.

**Edit 1:**

If the value is passed as a prop with name `location`, you can do following:

```js
initialValues={{ [location]: initialValue }}
// or
initialValues={{ [props.location]: initialValue }}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-river-lhbrej?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: Thanks @codedump for taking a look. Only thing is I can't use "key.location". This value is coming in as props location. I have updated the question. How to reference props location inside the initialValues object so that it takes it as "key.location"?

Comment: Checkout my edit @ArrRaj! I have updated sandbox as well!